# unexpected keyword argument 'orient' error when printing dataframe from train & test data after splitting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a function that splits the dataset into train & test. The result is supposed to be a dataframe returned as a dictionary, row-wise.

**Code**

```
def balance_dataset_fun(df, target_variable):    
    # Splitting the dataset
    X = df.drop(target_variable, axis=1)
    y = df[target_variable]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
      
    return (X_train.to_dict(orient='records'), X_test.to_dict(orient='records'), y_train.to_dict(orient='records'), y_test.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

**error:**

```
return (X_train.to_dict(orient='records'), X_test.to_dict(orient='records'), y_train.to_dict(orient='records'), y_test.to_dict(orient='records'))
TypeError: to_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'orient'
```

The dataframe is being returned in the expected format only when the return statement returns a single dataframe, i.e., `(X_train.to_dict(orient='records') (or) X_test.to_dict(orient='records') (or) y_train.to_dict(orient='records') (or) y_test.to_dict(orient='records').`
When I try to print all 4 datasets at once, it gives the TypeError: to_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'orient'.

How do I solve this? The commonly suggested solution is re-installing Pandas or upgrading it to the latest version. I've tried them all. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `y_train` and `y_test` are only one-dimensional pandas [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html), not [DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html). You should not use `orient` for Series.
Indeed the [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for DataFrames takes an agrument `orient`, but not [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) for Series.

You can either:

**1. Avoid using `orient` for the Series:**

```py
return (X_train.to_dict(orient='records'), X_test.to_dict(orient='records'), y_train.to_dict(), y_test.to_dict())
```

**or**

**2. Define `y` as a DataFrame and not Series:**

```py
def balance_dataset_fun(df, target_variable):    
    # Splitting the dataset
    X = df.drop(target_variable, axis=1)
    y = df[[target_variable]] # double brackets make a DataFrame if target_variable is a string.
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
      
    return (X_train.to_dict(orient='records'), X_test.to_dict(orient='records'), y_train.to_dict(orient='records'), y_test.to_dict(orient='records'))
```